# JAXB xml tag in file starting with number, possible?

Tags: java, xml, spring, jaxb, oxm

I have a very big xml with many nested tags for which I generated a java class.

One of the tags starts with number `<3DSecure></3DSecure>`

I had to manually set this tag only, in Java I mapped to `threeDSecure`.

I know this is against XML Conventions but is it possible to override this check? Otherwise I will have to drop JAXB and setup the xml manually because I don't control the API which expects this XML.

When unmarshalling/marshalling I get the error:

```
[org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: The content of elements must consist of well-formed character data or markup.]
    at javax.xml.bind.helpers.AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.createUnmarshalException(AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.java:315)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.createUnmarshalException(UnmarshallerImpl.java:505)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal0(UnmarshallerImpl.java:206)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(UnmarshallerImpl.java:173)
    at javax.xml.bind.helpers.AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.java:137)
    at javax.xml.bind.helpers.AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.java:142)
    at javax.xml.bind.helpers.AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.java:151)
    at javax.xml.bind.helpers.AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.java:169)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `-nv` flag, do disable validation of the XML schema when generating classes from an XML schema.

**XJC Call**

```
xjc -nv schema.xsd
```

**XML Schema (schema.xsd)**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<schema 
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
    targetNamespace="http://www.example.org/schema"
    xmlns:tns="http://www.example.org/schema" 
    elementFormDefault="qualified">

    <complexType name="foo">
       <sequence>
           <element name="3DSecure" type="string"/>
       </sequence>
    </complexType>

</schema>
```

**Generated Class (Foo)**

```
package org.example.schema;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "foo", propOrder = {"_3DSecure"})
public class Foo {

    @XmlElement(name = "3DSecure", required = true)
    protected String _3DSecure;

    public String get3DSecure() {
        return _3DSecure;
    }

    public void set3DSecure(String value) {
        this._3DSecure = value;
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for your effort, I have already tried that it didn't work. But nevermind cause the API had an obsolete doc, I don't need this feature :)

Comment: @braincell - Strange to hear that it didn't work for you.  Happy to hear its not blocking you.

Answer (score 0):

Bind your Java class property using [@XmlElement](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlElement.html) annotation's *name* attribute as

```
 @XmlRootElement
 public class JAXBModel {

     @XmlElement(name="3DSecure")
     public String threeDSecure;

     // ...
 }
```